# Notifications for file system changed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm implementing a free space on disk bar where while files are being copied, the free space bar updates. I need some way of being notified of file system changes. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [File System Events Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) has all the info you need. You want to register with the File System Events API (OS X 10.5 and later).

Comment: Stu Connolly has a great Objective-C wrapper for the FSEvents C API called SCEvents. You can get it here:

http://stuconnolly.com/blog/scevents-011/

Comment: The above links are dead, so here we go: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html

Answer (score 2):

To monitor operations on individual files you can use kqueue file change notifications. Uli Kusterer has a nice Obj-C wrapper called UKKQueue.

You can get it here: http://zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm

If you want to watch an entire folder, FSEvents (and the SCEvents wrapper) will probably be of more use.

Comment: Up-to-date versions of this code can now be found at GitHub: http://github.com/uliwitness/UliKit